A Force Perpendicular to the Velocity changes only the direction of motion?
Why does a force that remains perpendicular to velocity alaways only change the direction of the motion(circular) and not induce a velocity in the perpendicular direction???

Have you tried drawing how this would look?

drawing would indicate the direction,im much more concerned about the magnitude right now!!

How much work does a force perpendicular to displacement do?

thats zero obviously but i would like to have a more intuitive approach to the problem


change the direction of the motion(circular) and not induce a velocity in the perpendicular direction

One thing to be careful of in this context is the phrase “the perpendicular direction”. The perpendicular direction changes over time. So there is no one direction that qualifies as the perpendicular direction.
A direction is only the perpendicular direction for an instant. During that instant a perpendicular force does induce a velocity in that instantaneously perpendicular direction. That is what makes the velocity vector change direction.
What you are probably more interested in is why it doesn’t change the speed. That is covered here Why does force perpendicular to the velocity change only its direction; not the speed?

seems fair enough but i m not able to feel that honestly

The word 'perpendicular' indicates a force direction that neither adds to
nor subtracts from the forward momentum of the object in question.
That is where momentum change is only in direction, not magnitude,
because the continuum of possible force-direction effects switches sign
at exactly the perpendicular condition.
The only value possible when a smooth curve switches sign, is zero.


Why does a force that remains perpendicular to velocity alaways [sic] only change the direction of the motion(circular) [sic] and not induce a velocity in the perpendicular direction???

Suppose the net force $\vec F$ is always perpendicular to the velocity $\vec v$. In this case the net work is clearly zero:
$$
W_{net}=\int \vec F \cdot d\vec x = \int \vec F \cdot \vec v dt = 0\;.
$$
But, the net work must equal the change in kinetic energy, by the work-kinetic-energy theorem (which I will not prove here). Thus
$$
\frac{1}{2}m\left(v_f^2 - v_i^2\right) = 0\;,
$$
where the initial and final times are arbitrary. Therefore the magnitude of the velocity is constant.
In other words, in the case of interest, the magnitude of the velocity (the speed) can not change (as we have just shown), but the direction of the velocity can change.
